# Location of Metro GUI Elements

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to know basic information about Windows 8 Metro GUI elements (size of objects, coordinate position on the screen, whether the cursor is hovering over them or not). I've tried searching here and looking through the Win 8 API documentation and I've seen many solutions for finding this information about a Metro app but in my case I want this information about the home page and arbitrary apps.

Thanks again!

Comment: Read [FAQ] of stack overflow first.

Comment: To be a little more clear, you need to focus your question more.  Right now it is quite broad and has multiple elements.  Pick one and make sure it's specific enough to have a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few parts to your question.

For 'size of objects', you'll have to be more specific. There's their 'requested size' and then there's their 'actual size'. 'Actual' size can be gained from 'ActualHeight' and 'ActualWidth', two properties of either `FrameworkElement` or `UIElement`. I forget which.

For 'coordinate position on screen'. You'll need to do `myuielement.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content).TransformPoint(new Point(0,0))`. This will give you a Point which is the top left corner.

For `whether the cursor is hovering over them or not`, you'll have to hook into their events. `PointerEntered`, `PointerExited`, etc. You can also get their bounding Rects relative to the screen and do manual calculations for each item each time the pointer moves, if you absolutely need to.

Anyway, as David said, give a look to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you are better received next time around.

Hope this helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks Nate. Question: do those APIs work for the metro home screen as well (e.g. Microsoft's content, not my own apps)?

Comment: You cannot access other apps or Start Screen info from inside of an app container, so I believe not.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to get that information for the Start Screen?

Comment: What do you mean? Like, the position of your app in the Start Screen? The apps that are currently pinned? The information in your Live Tile? Or do you mean the position of the start screen?